# Taylor Series Calc 2

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

From Rogawski ET 2e section 10.7, exercise 9.

> Find the Maclaurin series for $f(x) = \ln(1 - 6x^5)$.
>
> $$\ln(1-6x^5) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} [\textrm{__________}]$$
>
> On what interval is the expansion valid?

I am not sure how to find a series representation for the natural log. If anyone can show me some helpful steps to solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated. What is the Maclaurin series for $\ln(x)$?

Comment: Start with the simpler function $\ln(1-u)$. Then replace $u$ with $6x^5$. Don't forget to do the same in the inequality representing the interval of convergence. You know how to compute the coefficients in terms of derivatives, right? Coefficient of $x^n$ is $f^{(n)}(0)/n!$. And you know how to differentiate the natural log, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm still quite confused. It could be the computer program that is not accepting the answer because it is very sensitive. Or I am not doing it correctly. The sum of (-1/6)^(n-1)/(-x^5)^n/n from n=1 to infinity. This is the most recent answer I tried.

Comment: That's close, but not what I got. For $n\geq 1$, I have the $n$th derivative of $\ln x$ is $(n-1)!(1-x)^n$. This ends up giving me $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-6^nx^{5n}}{n}$. And don't forget about the interval of convergence.

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful!

Comment: You cannot create a polynomial expression to represent natural log, centered at 0, because it is undefined at zero. As such, a Maclaurin series does not exist.